# Linq select from list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq

I cant seem to figure this out, I'm not that new to the MVC model but perhaps my brain is just tired.

**View Model**

```
Public Class CategoriesViewModel
    Public Property Categories As List(Of cihCategoryOrgDef)
    Public Property Category As cihCategoryOrgDef
    Public Property SelectedItem As String

    Public Sub New(organizationId As Guid, codId As Guid)
        Categories = lists.organizationClubCategories
        Category = From x In Categories
                   Where x.codId = codId
                   Select x
    End Sub
    End Class
```

**CategoriesController**

```
   Function Edit(codId As Guid) As ActionResult
        Dim model As CategoriesViewModel = New CategoriesViewModel(ZenCommon.CurrentOrgId, codId)


        Return View(model)
    End Function
```

When I run this, I get a "invalid cast exception" on the `Category = From x....` line

```
Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectListIterator`2[Library.cihCategoryOrgDef,Library.cihCategoryOrgDef]' to type 'Library.cihCategoryOrgDef'.
```

I'm trying to get a single `Category` to use in my View. So I can have an edit page for that specific category. Am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Category` is a *single* category, you need to make sure your LINQ returns a single result. If you're sure that the query will only return one value, use `SingleOrDefault`:

```
Category = (From x In Categories
           Where x.codId = codId
           Select x).SingleOrDefault()
```

If your query could return more than one result and you only want to take the first result, use `FirstOrDefault`:

```
Category = (From x In Categories
           Where x.codId = codId
           Select x).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your select actually returns a collection, that's why you get invalid cast exception. To get only one item you need something like this (sorry, I'm not very much familiar with vb, so here is c# code):

```
Category = (From x In Categories
               Where x.codId = codId
               Select x).DefaultIfEmpty(null).FirstOrDefault();
```